# Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem and Pareto Efficient Allocation

Tags: mathematical-economics

Wikipedia says 'The Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem allows one to prove that if the set of allocations is compact and non-empty, then the system has a Pareto-efficient allocation.' 
However, I couldn't find a compelling simple proof for this theorem anywhere. Could someone provide a proof for the theorem in a simple fashion that is understandable for Undergrad students in Economics who have done a course in Analysis?

Comment: In order to understand any of the proofs you have to grasp either the concept of "nested intervals" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals ) or the concept of a subsequence. If you get those the proof is straight foreward. Anyway these arent complicated. They are taught in intro to analysis in all undergrad programs in math.

Comment: Perhaps insofar as Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem is [used to prove the extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Proof_of_the_extreme_value_theorem), which in turn can be invoked to easily establish the existence of Pareto optimality. See also: https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-Bolzano-Weierstrass-theorem-used-in-general-equilibrium-theory/answer/Amit-Goyal-135

Answer (score 1):

What one needs are two facts:

1. **Scalarization/Sufficiency for Pareto Optimality**
   Suppose the economy has finitely many agents $u_i$, $i = 1, \cdots, I$, with feasible allocations given by some $X \subset \mathbb{R}^I$. If
   $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_I) \in X$ solves the problem
   $$
   \max_{x \in X} \sum_{i=1}^I \lambda_i u_i(x_i),
   $$
   where $\lambda_i > 0$ for all $i$, then $x$ is Pareto optimal. This maximization problem is called the social planner's problem with social weights $\lambda_i$.
   (The converse is not true. In other words, not all Pareto allocations arise as such, not even when $u_i$'s are concave.)
2. Continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets. (The Bolzano–Weierstrass gives a characterization of compactness on $\mathbb{R}^n$---closed and bounded.)

So if the preferences are continuous and feasible set $X$ is compact, existence of Pareto optimal allocation follows immediately. Choose any social weights $\lambda_i > 0$. A solution of the resulting social planner's problem is a Pareto optimal allocation.